# Create Dynamic Object Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, object, facebook-opengraph

I'm sure this is a simple solution but I'm new to Facebook apps.

I have a custom object called user which is tied to a custom action type recommended. I'm trying to get the open graph post to say the following:

**NAME Recommended NAME on Website.**

I have everything working except I don't see how I can pass the second Name dynamically as it's from my website and changes.

For example Mike Johnson Recommended **Chris Marcus** on Google.com How do I get Chris Marcus inserted to the object dynamically?

Thanks